# Flash not being called by Javascript on different domain

Tags: javascript, html, flash, apache-flex

I am trying to use Javascript to call a flash function. I have it working when the html file and the swf are on the same domain, but it stops working when it is on another domain.

Here is the cross domain file I have on the server with the SWF:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
   <!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
   <cross-domain-policy>
<site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all"/>
   <allow-access-from domain="*" />
   <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*"/>
   </cross-domain-policy>
```

The SWF is previously loaded with:

```
AC_FL_RunContent("src", "http://www.eyespeakpro.com/OneSentenceLogin.swf",
    "width", "100%",
    "height", "80%",
    "align", "middle",
    "id", "OneSentenceLogin",
    "quality", "high",
    "bgcolor", "#ffffff",
    "name", "OneSentenceLogin",
    "allowScriptAccess","sameDomain",
    "type", "application/x-shockwave-flash",
    "pluginspage", "http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"
);
```

Here is the javascript code that fails when it is part of a html page on another server. The SWF is called OneSentenceLogin, and the function is callChangeSentIn.

```
 function callExternalInterface(sentIn) {
    /* Call a function registered as callChangeSentIn in the SWF named myMovie. */
    getMovieName("OneSentenceLogin").callChangeSentIn(sentIn); 

// The following error only happens on the other server:
// Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLEmbedElement> has no method 'callChangeSentIn'

    }
    /* This utility function resolves the string movieName to a Flash object reference based on browser type. */
    function getMovieName(movieName) {
    if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") != -1) {
    return window[movieName]
    }
    else {
    return document[movieName]
    }
 }
```

Why is the method callChangeSentIn not being found when it is called from another server, even though the swf is still loading?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting allowScriptAccess to always.

[More info](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/control-access-scripts-host-web.html)

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. I have change the html file to AC_FL_RunContent(
   "src", "http://www.eyespeakpro.com/OneSentenceLogin.swf",
   "width", "100%",
   "height", "80%",
   "align", "middle",
   "id", "OneSentenceLogin",
   "quality", "high",
   "bgcolor", "#ffffff",
   "name", "OneSentenceLogin",
   "allowScriptAccess","always",
   "type", "application/x-shockwave-flash",
   "pluginspage", "http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"
 );
However it makes no difference.
Am I supposed to change the crossdomain.xml file as well, if so how?

Answer (score 0):

This was what was needed in the swf as it loaded:
Security.allowDomain("www.example.com")
In my case I put in

```
Security.allowDomain("74.52.88.189");
Security.allowDomain("http://74.52.88.189");
Security.allowDomain("http://74.52.88.189/");
```

Not sure which one in particular was necessary.

It was also answered here, but I didn't find it for some reason.
[Flash not being called by Javascript on different domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13279202/flash-not-being-called-by-javascript-on-different-domain)

Comment: Use allowDomain and allowInsecureDomain. Your second and third call is actually an indirect call to `allowInsecureDomain`, since you pass in a url using HTTP, but you should prefer the explicit call instead. There for what you should need is `Security.allowDomain(x); Security.allowInsecureDomain(x);`.